# How do I pass two parameters with a NSTimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have this `void`

```
-(void)MoveMissile:(UIImageView *)Missile mtimer:(NSTimer *)MissileTimer{
    // lines of code here
}
```

and this NSTimer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.025 target:self selector:@selector(MoveMissile:mtimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I want to pass the `NSTimer` as the second parameter, and a `UIImageView` called `Missile1` as the first parameter.

How do I pass these two parameters?

Comment: Hint, if you need to pass more than one value in the userInfo, use an NSDictionary to hold the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:):

> aSelector
>
> The message to send to target when the timer fires. The
>   selector should have the following signature: timerFireMethod:
>   (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument). The
>   timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the
>   following pattern:
>
> ```
> - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
> ```

So, you have to work with a method that takes a single parameter, and pass a reference to the image view in via the timers userInfo, like so.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.025
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(missileTimerMethod:)
                               userInfo:anImageViewReference
                                repeats:YES];


- (void)missileTimerMethod:(NSTimer *)missileTimer
{
    UIImageView *theImageView = (UIImageView *)missileTimer.userInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it the way you're trying. The selector for the timer hast to have zero or one parameters, and if it has one, that has to be the timer (the signature for the method is clearly spelled out in the NSTimer class reference). However, you can pass any object you want in the userInfo parameter. So pass your image view as the userInfo.